# MYSQL Combing Two tables From Multiple Row

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two tables, one is for all products, the other is for new purchases products.

**Product Table**

```
Item    Qty
301       2
302       5
303       3
304       4
305       6
```

**Purchases Table**

```
Item     Qty    Status    Date
302       5     used      09-15-2015
303       5     reserve   09-20-2015
301       5     used      09-20-2015
302       5     reserve   09-20-2015
304       5     used      10-15-2015
303       5     reserve   10-15-2015
```

I want to display how many quantity in the product table, and join the quantity of `purchases table` to `Product Table`

This is my initial sql query

```
SELECT product_name, product_quantity, quantity 
FROM products 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON products.ID = purchases.product_ID 
WHERE product_status !='deleted' AND status != 'used'`.
```

However, it only returned the the items from `purchases table` that is reserve.

what I want to achieve is

```
Item    Qty    Reserved Qty    Total
301       2     0                 2
302       5     5                 10
303       3     10                13
304       4     0                 4
305       6     0                 6
```

**UPDATE**
New sql query

```
SELECT product_name, product_quantity, p.quantity 
FROM products 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM purchases 
        WHERE status = 'reserved' 
        GROUP BY product_ID) AS  p ON p.product_ID = products.ID 
WHERE products.product_status !='deleted'`
```

But it returns 0 on reserved qty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there in terms of your query except that you need to sum the quantity of reserved items and then use `GROUP BY`, sort of like this

```
SELECT
    pd.item AS 'Item', pd.qty AS 'Qty', IFNULL(pr.reserved_quantity, 0) AS 'Reserved Qty', (pd.qty+IFNULL(pr.reserved_quantity, 0)) AS 'Total'
FROM
    product pd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT item, SUM(qty) AS 'reserved_quantity' FROM purchases WHERE `status`='reserve' GROUP BY 1) AS pr ON pd.item=pr.item
```

Comment: Thanks it works... though their are some columns that doesn't much, I get the whole idea. Thank you so much...

Comment: @NimitzE. i used same column names as provided by yourself in your question, even then it should be a minor thing as long as you get the idea. glad to help

Comment: Oh one more thing, I have deleted items in table 1, where should i place the `where clause`? what I mean, is that I have a column for status and its value is deleted, I don't want to display those deleted items.

Comment: if its in `product` table then you'll have to add new `WHERE` after `ON pd.item=pr.item`. if its in `purchases` table then you'll have to add a new condition after `where status='reserve'

Comment: Thanks man, this is my first kind of query, what is the name of this query? select-left-join-select?

Comment: it can be called `LEFT JOIN` with sub query

Comment: Then if my understanding is correct, the 1 in group by 1 is first column of the current query (inside the parenthesis).

Thanks again :)

Comment: spot on, 1 stands for the first column. `GROUP BY 1` in the sub query is equal to `GROUP BY item`. you are welcome